# Is it possible to avoid downloading song up to the supplied position using SoundManager2 and the SoundCloud JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I'm using the [SoundManager2 JavaScript SDK](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/) on a site that streams synchronized audio from [SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com) to multiple clients simultaneously. When a new user loads the page, the audio is loaded, and a position parameter is set to specify where playback should begin.

The problem arises when the track is really long (say 60 minutes), and the current track position is substantially far into the track (e.g. 30 minutes). When this is the case, it takes a really long time before playback begins because the track has to download/buffer up to the current position. Is there a way to avoid downloading the 30 minutes of audio that I don't need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, no. We are looking into some alternatives for the current progressive download system, and hopefully could have something publicly available in a few months.